# Mongoose Express .delete() .update() doesn't always return the updated view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to tweek my .delete() method in my router so when I delete an object (favorite in this case) the result show immediatly. Sometimes the result will show up when the resquest is send but must of the time I have to refresh the browser to see the result.

**The method goes as followed :**

```
favoriteRouter.route('/:dishObjectId')

.delete(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
var dishObjectId = req.params.dishObjectId
var userId = req.decoded._id;
Favorites.update({ postedBy: userId }, { $pull: { dishes: dishObjectId } },
    function (err, favorite) {
        if (err) next(err);
        res.json(favorite);
    });
});
```

The method basically works fine but I just can't find a way to always show the result without having to refresh the whole browser.
I'm working on a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold try to use `{new: true}`since this way your query will return the object modified.
Try with:

```
Favorites.update({ postedBy: userId }, { $pull: { dishes: dishObject } }, {new: true}, function (err, favorite) {
    if (err) next(err);
    res.json(favorite);
    });
});
```